# Angular5 MongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, angular5

I wanted to ask everyone a specification, if I wanted to create a project in Angular5 and as a database I wanted to use MongoDB, should I follow the MEAN programming (MongoDB, Express, Angular, NodeJS) or can I even use ANgular and MOngoDB?

Comment: It depends on your project and what you want to do, but the two options are possible. The MEAN architecture is not mandatory if the project doesn't require it

Comment: Depends on what ? What are the factors for which I should use MEAN?

Comment: I was writing an answer but @KimKern one is better. MEAN is a good one because it is well documented, but there a lot of other possibilities yes.

Comment: Still having open questions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Angular applications are always on the client side. Hence, you cannot directly use a (classical) database with it. If you want to use mongo, you have to setup a server side application. For this, have a look at [nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/), which is a really great framework for creating server side applications that you can then query via a REST API from your Angular application.

If you don't need a server-side API (e. g. to persist data or do reliable business logic) you can use a client side browser *database* like [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

Another possibility is to use a service like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), which gives you the ability to store data on a server without having to setup a full backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular with the back-end Technology you prefer, node or php, or .Net etc.
You can use mongo without angular, you don't have to care of the front-end.
MEAN is a stack that use express as back-end framework. 
It's simpler than node api, and you can use odm to map mongodb like mongoose.
Another advantage is that you will write code in js, in front and back end